# Odd results using jQuery rating plugin

Tags: php, jquery, plugins, rating

I use a for loop to generate my stars. I want them split into four so I use

```
class="star {split:4}"
```

I want 5 stars, so I need 20 loops (4splits * 5stars = 20). When it hits 17, it echo's

```
 checked="checked"
```

However, in the browser, my script displays 30 stars with 25 and a quarter stars highlighted!

Here's my line in PHP

```
<input type="radio" class="star {split:4}" disabled="disabled" <?php echo $i == $row['rating'] ? 'checked="checked"' : "" ?>/>
```

Also, I do have the metadata plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.. each set of stars needs to have a unique name. Durr